# Bug on Chrome Remote Desktop when using Windows + V

Tags: chrome-remote-desktop

I've a bug when I use the <kbd>Windows</kbd>  + <kbd>V</kbd> (Clipboard history for Windows 10/11).

It works but on the remote machine, I've this message displayed after I've pasted the item:

[image]

Have you got the same problem ? It's not blocking but it's a little bit annoying...